# Angular 8: Can I use ngx-barcode in window.open?

Tags: angular, barcode, window.open

Can I use ngx-barcode in window.open?
And how?

```
  modalPrint.document.write('<tr><td class="text-center"><ngx-barcode [bc-value]="value" [bc-display-value]="true"></ngx-barcode></td></tr>');
```

This is not working.
Or I need to add a library something?

Comment: Please explain the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You should import document object inside your angular component in this way:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
So you can use it as the following :

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
      document.write(your_code_here);
  }
}
```